# How to synchronize a Java Object with a Database table with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa, synchronization

I have a game (like chess) that I persist as sequence of steps (as Step object, Game is a set of Steps).

Board: the game board where it will hold 28 positions (64 positions for chess), which is not persisted entity.

When a player moves it updates one position and I persist the step.

Now when a second user plays I need to load the game (need to populate all the steps happen till now ) and ask him to play.

In this way, I am always loading game by populating the game from steps.

Is there any way in Hibernate or Java applications, where I can keep the gameBoard object in memory and I do merge the step so as not to populate the board every time?

I want to load the game only when it is not available in the Java heap as an object?

Can anybody suggest a way to so this or guide me if I am thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize the Object Model with the Database, you only have to persist the new `Step` and commit the transaction (which [flushes the Persistence Context](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/) automatically).